# R - Creating a class with a list attribute

Tags: r, list, class, r-s4, slots

I am pretty new using R in an advanced way...so apologize for futile questions!
I want to create a object of class S4, defined by 3 slots. Thing is that I can't manage to create these attributes as a list. Here is my code :

```
test<-setClass("dblist",representation(df.list="list", df.para="list",df.coups="list"))
new("dblist",representation(df.list="list", df.para="list",df.coups="list"))
```

and the error I get :

```
Error in initialize(value, ...) : cannot use object of class “list” in new():  class   
“dblistpgn” does not extend that class
```

Could you please explain how creating an object with list plot?
Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
new("dblist", df.list = list(), df.para = list(), df.coups = list())
```